# JQuery DataTables Conditionally Show Button If >= 2 checkboxes are checked

Tags: jquery, datatables

using JQuery DataTables how can I have a button 'show' if the user selects more than 1 checkbox in the DataTable?

```
title: "Modify",
data: "id" ,
width: "10%",
className: "text-center",
render: function (data, type, full, meta){
    return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
}
```

and this is how I set-up the checkbox.  This is just the snippet of my jquery datatable where i have the checkbox...if more code is needed please let me know